# SQL how to avoid duplicate result

Tags: sql

Would you please give some tips or recommended code to avoid duplicate result in below condition?

TransactionTable as t

```
ProductID, SoldQuantity, SoldDate
x123, 2, "2020-01-01"
y123, 1, "2020-01-01"
```

ProductDetail as pd

```
ProductID, Specific, Value
x123, Brand, Nintendo
x123, Brand, nintendo
x123, Size, 10cm
x123, Type, camera
y123, Brand, Xbox
y123, Brand, xbox
y123, Size, 50cm
y123, Type, car
```

My code is below

```
SELECT
t.ProductID, 
sum(t.SoldQuantity),
pd.Value as Brand

from TransactionTable as p
left join
ProductDetail as pd
on p.ProductID = pd.ProductID
Where
p.SoldDate between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-30"
group by p.ProductID,pd.Value as Brand
```

Result from above code

```
ProductID, SoldQuantity, Brand
x123, 2, Nintendo
x123, 2, nintendo
y123, 1, Xbos
y123, 1, xbos
```

Expected result

```
ProductID, SoldQuantity, Brand
x123, 2, Nintendo
y123, 1, Xbox
```

Brand spelling does not matter, I would like to count sold quantity without duplication.

I have tried distinct, Max(), and AVE(), but all do not work this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use meaningful table aliases.  And single quotes for date constants.

To solve your problem, it looks like you need to put the values in lower case:

```
select pd.ProductID, sum(t.SoldQuantity),
       lower(pd.Value) as Brand
from TransactionTable t join
     ProductDetail pd
     on t.ProductID = pd.ProductID
where t.SoldDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
group by pd.ProductID, lower(pd.Value);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your comment and advice. I have tried you code, but it shows duplication outcome again. It would be appreciated if you have another option to solve this.